# How to edit help_text of a child in the parent class

Tags: python, django, oop

I made a mixin (same as the parent class) for my **brand** model, and I want to get the class name of the children and replace it with **help_text** in the **parent** class. Is there any solution?

```
class TitleSlugMixin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        _('title'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_(f'{self.__class__.__name__} title.')
    )
```

```
class Brand(TitleSlugMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: `TitleSlugMixin` should be an `Abstract Model` , and you can't use `self` outside of a class method scope.

Comment: @MikeJones Thanks, mike. I know we can't use self outside of a class method scope. But can we reach the child class name when we use the parent class inside the parent scope?

Comment: Unfortunately, i am not aware of any method that can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**A lot** of `vars()` later, it is possible:

**Note:** I tested this on a similar inheritance setup, but my field was `machine` *(No underscore)* so you might have to add that underscore (See debugging `__init__` & My commented line)

##### Models.py

```py
class TitleSlugMixin(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        _('title'),
        max_length=255,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # Dynamically Change Help Text
        self.__class__.title.field.help_text = '{0} title'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
```

---

##### Debugging `__init__`

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()

    print('name', self.__class__.__name__)

    # This is where you could see all the available fields
    # Note: You'll have to clean this data up to view it reasonably 
    print('class', vars(self.__class__))

    print('help text, before', self.__class__.title.field.help_text)

    self.__class__.title.field.help_text = '{0} title'.format(self.__class__.__name__)

    print('help after, after', self.__class__.title.field.help_text)

    # # Other:
    # print('title', vars(self.__class__.title))
    # print('field', vars(self.__class__.title.field))
```

- Steps:

  1. Take note of a **Single** Pk for a Brand Object (helps reduce text dump, for step #4)
  2. Replace `__init__` with code below
  3. `python manage.py shell`
  4. Import Brand Model
  5. `o = Brand.objects.get(pk=pk_from_step_1)` => vars() Output
  6. Clean up, *optional*:

     - Copy Dictionary & Paste into Text Editor
     - Replace all `,` with New Lines (`\n` or `\r` depending)